# How to parse XML response using HttpClient in .Net 4.0 to .Net Class?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, httpclient

I have a web service that return xml in response.

Below is a screenshot of he xml response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Header>
        <Message type="String"></Message>
    </Header>
    <Output>
        <Rows>
            <Row>
                <Result type="Integer">1021806</Result>
            </Row>
        </Rows>
    </Output>
</Root>
```

Here is my .net Model that represent the xml response :

```
    public class ResponseModel
    {
        public class Root
        {
            public Header header { get; set; }
            public Output output { get; set; }
        }
        public class Header
        {
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
        public class Output
        {
            public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
        } 
        public class Row
        {
            public int Result { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I am using `HttpClient` Class to send the request the specified web service.

Here is my code :

```
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
         var response = client.GetAsync("myWebServiceUrl").Result;
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
            var responseContent = response.Content; 
         }
     }
```

`responseContent` has three methods :

```
ReadAsStringAsync()
ReadAsStreamAsync()
ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
```

What are the differences between the three methods?

Which one should I use for xml response and how to parse the xml to the required `ResponseModel`?

Comment: Do you share the model-code between service an client?

Comment: Why are you accessing the web service in that way? Why not use it as a ServiceReference in VS?

Comment: What do you mean ? can you elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a 'DataContractSerializer' and use the ReadObject mehod ? It would look more or less like this :

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ResponseModel.Root));
var stream = await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var response = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as ResponseModel;
```

Comment: Do I need to pass a root element in the ReadObject method ?

Comment: yes the serialiser expect a ResponseModel.Root type, I will modify my answer

Comment: you may have to change your model to put caps in header and output or use the 'DataContractAttribute' on your fields with names differing from the service response :  [DataMember(Name = "Output")]

Comment: one thing I did since I have .net 4.0 so I removed await and called .Result in  ReadAsStreamAsync(); so it became var stream =  responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result; will that affect your answer ?